# updating specific objects of array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want update only specific object from default _data i.e (isconformed value to 1) when user click confirm button that should object isconformed value to 1 and api put call to set the change value in data?

```
 const default_data = {
   Id: "",
   productname: "",
   price:"",
   isconformed:0,
 }
 const[data,setData]=useState(default_data)
    
      
 const OnChangeHandler = (key, value) => {
   //console.log(value)  i.e value will be 1 here
   setData({ ...data, [key]: value });
 };
     
const Confirmproduct = () => {
  const res_data = {
   isConformed: data.isConfirmed,
  };
        
 //API call
 axios.put(`${config.APP_CONFIG}/Product/${Id}`, res_data)
  .then((res) => {
   setdata(res.data)
  })
 }

 onClick={(e) => {
  //when button clicked
  e.preventDefault(); 
  OnChangeHandler("isConformed", 1);
  Confirmproduct()
 }}

}
```

**My expected output**

```
{
 Id: "",
 productname: "",
 price:"",
 isconformed:1,
}
```

Comment: would you correcting the syntax errors in your code so that the formatting works? I'd also recommend separating your expected output into a separate code block to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Christian Fritz just formating the code and expected output in seperate block

Answer (score 0):

The `setData` function is an asynchronous hook which, when called, does not update immediately the value of data as, for example, using `default_data["isconfirmed"]=value`.

My recommendation is to simplify and remove the handle function as you don't need it

```
const default_data = {
    Id: "",
    productname: "",
    price:"",
 isconformed:0,
}


const[data,setdata]=useState(default_data)

 
const Confirmproduct = (key, value) => {
    // setData({ ...data, [key]: value }); <- Do you really need this?

    const res_data = {
        isConformed: value 
    };
//API call

    axios.put(`${config.APP_CONFIG}/Product/${Id}, res_data)
      .then((res) => {
       setdata(res.data)
})


**  button click event**


onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();              
    Confirmproduct("isConformed", 1);
    }}
```

Comment: onchangehandler i want to append that specific so that i can pass data to another form with isconformed:1 and check other flag